# How do you type the ₿ Bitcoin Symbol in Android Google Keyboard?

Tags: android, bitcoin-symbol

Is there a way to enable the Bitcoin symbol on my Android 9 Google Keyboard? I don't see it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Gboard settings (cogwheel on keyboard) > Dictionary > Personal Dictionary > (your language) > + button

For the shortcut box, add whatever symbol or word you want that will make the symbol appear on the autocorrect list in the moddle. Copy and paste the symbol for the shortcut field.

Yours may vary. Razer Phone 2, Android 9, Gboard v9.1.8

Comment: This worked for me. I put the shortcut "btcsym" which then proposes the symbol for correction when I typed it.

Answer (score 0):

When u press $ there should be :)

[image: press $]

Comment: This doesn't look ... are you sure this is the Google keyboard and not the iOS keyboard?

Comment: Im pretty sure that it is Google keyboard

Comment: Could you be more specific what input language and Android version this is? Following your instructions, the Bitcoin symbol does not show up in English (US) on stock Android 10 when I get related symbols for $. The keys are also located in different positions for me.